# Remove rectangular box from end of the long text in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

Remove rectangular box from end of the long text

[image]

below is the code for long text

```
return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 5),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Text(
                  subjectName,
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  style: GoogleFonts.sourceSansPro(
                      fontSize: 14,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                      color: AppColors.color072346),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 3,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

using `overflow: TextOverflow.clip,` UI will be
[image]
want to display 3 dots for log text. how to achieve this. how remove to box from end of the long text in flutter web.
Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of canvas use html renderer, solved the problem for me.
Use

```
flutter run -d chrome --web-renderer html
```

for building.

But the html renderer could lead to performance issues ...

Instead of this option you could also change you font. GoogleFonts should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/TextOverflow-class.html
Read the documentation for the TextOverflow enum.
I guess you need to change TextOverflow.ellipsis to TextOverflow.clip .

Comment: I want to show 3 dots for long text. how can i achieve this?

Comment: .clip doesn't work. updated the question with images.

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate the width, and specify width to enable `TextOverflow.ellipsis`

```dart
Container(
  width: 120, // <--- you need to specify width 
  Text(
    subjectName,
    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
    style: GoogleFonts.sourceSansPro(
      fontSize: 14,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
      color: AppColors.color072346),
    ),
  ),
),
```